# Disable TCP Delayed ACKs

Tags: linux, tcp

I have an application that receives relatively sparse traffic over TCP with no application-level responses.  I believe the TCP stack is sending delayed ACKs (based on glancing at a network packet capture).  What is the recommended way to disable delayed-ACK in the network stack for a single socket?  I've looked at `TCP_QUICKACK`, but it seems that the stack will change it under my feet anyways.

This is running on a Linux 2.6 kernel, and I am not worried about portability.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could `setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (int[]){1}, sizeof(int))` after every `recv` you perform.  It appears that `TCP_QUICKACK` is only reset when there is data being sent or received; if you're not sending any data, then it will only get reset when you receive data, in which case you can simply set it again.

You can check this in the 14<sup>th</sup> field of `/proc/net/tcp`; if it is not 1, ACKs should be sent immediately... if I'm reading the TCP code correctly.  (I'm not an expert at this either.)

Comment: I believe he has done that already based on his question and he says  the value is being reset.

Comment: Setting `TCP_QUICKACK` immediately sends an ACK if there is anything that needs to be ACK'ed, so I think this is sufficient.

Comment: I am still `send()`ing on that socket.  But as I said, I am not responding to messages I receive.

I'll check out `/proc/net/tcp`.

Comment: Is it really the 14th field? See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243435/not-able-to-understand-and-map-output-of-proc-net-tcp) and [the explanations of all fields in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/proc_net_tcp.txt). Looks more like the 19th field to me.

Comment: @nh2 That diagram counts `010310AC:9C4C` as two fields, while I was counting it as one and skipping the initial `46:` identifier.

Comment: the 14th field of `/proc/net/tcp`...I assume you are talking about the `timeout` column on the 14th line? That's all zeroes for me so.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using the [setsockopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt) function you can use the `TCP_NODELAY` which will disable the Nagle algorithm.

*Edit* Found a link: [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-hisock.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20090609091530/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-hisock.html)

*Edit 2* Tom is correct. Nagle does not affect Delayed ACKs.

Comment: Disabling Nagle's algorithm won't impact delayed acknowledgements (at least, not on any implementation I know of).

Comment: No, disabling nagle impacts delayed ack, at least I can confirm in linux's very recent 3.17 kernel.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean "nagle does not impact Delayed ACKs"? They are independent options, that is true, but the combination of the two can have quite a big impact, which can cause unnecessary stalling in a TCP network, please read more, by Nagel himself - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10608356 and here fora more formal discussion: https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2016/tcp-nodelay-nagle-quickack-best-practices/#2

Answer (score 0):

<s>The accepted answer has a bug, it should be</s>

```
flags = 0;
flglen = sizeof(flags);
setsockopt(sfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, &flags, flglen)
```

(`SOL_TCP`, not `IPPROTO_TCP`)

<s>Post here in case someone need it.</s>

As @damolp suggested, it is not a bug. Keep it here for record.

Comment: Both macros are actually the same value on linux [```SOL_TCP```](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/include/linux/socket.h#L309)[```IPPROTO_TCP```](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/include/uapi/linux/in.h#L37-L38). I wouldn't call this a bug, as the man page (```man tcp```) states  ```call getsockopt(2) to read or setsockopt(2) to write the option with the option level argument set to IPPROTO_TCP```.